# How to check UDP IP and port is opened

Tags: go

How to check the UDP port and IP is opened?

I have checked the `net.DialUDP()` method but is showing the error ,

> "cannot assign requested address"

```
ln, err := net.DialUDP()
```

I want to result is "address already in use"

Comment: Are you passing as parameter the IP and the port as well ?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a udp ip and port are opened, try to listen on this port, ie to set up a server on this port. You will likely have an error that the `address is already in use.`

```
sAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "ipaddress:port")       
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
sConn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", sAddr)
if err != nil {
     log.Fatalln(err)
}
```